# Camtasia (Windows): We're Sorry! There Was a Problem with Your Recording File

Tags: camtasia

I tried to record a video with Camtasia Recorder, but got this error:

**Camtasia (Windows): We're Sorry! There Was a Problem with Your Recording File**

The file has no audio or video. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually with the sound device.

1. Unplug every recording device except the one you're using. So if you have a studio mic AND another mic (such as a webcam), unplug the other one.
2. Go to the Camtasia settings and change the recording format. **PCM** works but another may work for you as well.
3. Close an reopen Camtasia. Make sure the right recording device is selected. It should work now.